# Share on facebook time line

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have a publish_actions permission in my facebook app, I use it on iOS app, it works well, my app is on app store, my customers use the app and publish on time line on facebook. Now I added a Android plataform, to test the app Android I added a hashes key of my device on facebook configuration, this works very well on development tests. But now I published my app on google play console like Alpha test, and I shared my app to 20 customers test, but They dont publish on facebook time line, the app send a message "hash key dont exist". I need to add each hash of my user? There is a way to not use hash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate new keyhash from release keystore and add on https://developers.facebook.com/! Keyhash working on development devices is generated from debug keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Facebook share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

```
ShareContent shareContent = new ShareMediaContent.Builder()
.addMedium(sharePhoto1)
.build();

ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(...);
shareDialog.show(shareContent, Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```